# .htaccess detectar string depois do slash

Tags: regex, htaccess, url-rewrite

Não estou a conseguir que o htaccess detecte string ou caracteres depois da / por exemplo.

Eu tenho isto:

**xpto.xpto/xx/**

e queria que quando acontecesse isto

**xpto.xpto/xx/qualquecoisa**

o .htaccess internamente executasse um codigo php

eu tentei isto mas sem sucesso

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/xx/$ https://www.google.com/ [L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua Regex não contempla o que deseja.

Ela diz que pode ter qualquer coisa mas obrigatoriamente deve terminar com `/xx/`.
E o que você deseja é **qualquer coisa** + **/xx/** + **qualquer coisa**.

Que seria assim : `(.*)/xx/(.*)`.

Eu pessoalmente não acho esse tipo de Regex bom, pois não esta claro o suficiente. Assim a única coisa que diz é que deve conter `/xx/`.

Podendo aceitar :

```
xpto.xpto/xx/qualquecoisa/xx/qualquecoisa
xpto.xpto/xx/xx/
xpto.xpto/xx//xx/
```